# How to simulate r.v's from a joint pdf?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a joint pdf of two r.v's, x and y, which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi{(x+y)^{3}}}}e^{-\frac{\mu^{2}(x+y)}{2}}$$ I wish to obtain the marginal density of $y$, and then get its expectation and variance.

The question is when I tried to integrate the joint pdf wrt x, I found the integration is probably divergent and failed to get a closed form.

Also, is it possible to achieve it from Monte Carlo integration by using Gamma distribution?

Comment: You can fix your equation by adding "\$" dollar signs around it to make it display nicely. It looks like your integrals should converge assuming they are $(a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$. Here it is [calculated using an online integrator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2Fsqrt%282pi%28x%2By%29%5E3%29%20e%5E%28-m%5E2%28x%2By%29%2F2%29&ubound=%E2%88%9E&lbound=0&simplify=1) and does involve a Gamma function.

Comment: First, this probably lacks the conditions $$x\gt0,\qquad y\gt0.$$ Second, this probably lacks a prefactor $$\mu.$$ Third, one can probably use the representation $$Y=UZ^2$$ with $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Z$ standard normal and independent of $U$, to answer the question.

Comment: [Here is the integral of the marginal pdf of $Y$](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%CE%93%28%E2%88%921%2F2%2Cm%5E2y%2F2%29m%2F%282sqrt%28pi%29%29&intvar=y&ubound=%E2%88%9E&lbound=0&simplify=1) which does give $1/\mu$, so @Did is correct about the prefactor. This online calculator could not computer the mean of $Y$. I'm not certain whether or not $E(Y)$ exists, but it is possible for a random variable to not have a finite mean (see [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)).

Comment: @jdods Actually, my previous comment should be modified into $$Y=\frac1{\mu^2}UZ^2,$$ hence $E(Y)=\frac1{\mu^2}\cdot E(U)\cdot E(Z^2)=\frac1{\mu^2}\cdot\frac12\cdot1=\frac1{2\mu^2}$.

Comment: @Did, I agree with your calculation of $E(\frac{1}{\mu^2}UZ^2)$, however, can you provide some details on how you arrived at $Y=\frac{1}{\mu^2}UZ^2$? I can't quite seem to get it to work out...

Comment: @jdods Hint: Use the change of variables $\mu^2\cdot(x,y)=(1-u,u)\cdot z^2$.

Comment: @jdods  Many thanks for your kind help with the online calculator, and the integral of the y's density perfectly equals to 1, as well as the expectation going to be 1/2. Excellent!

Comment: @Did Thank you very much. Yes, $x$ and $y$ should be non-negative, and $\mu$ is positive parameter. The change of variables do good job, and it's consistent with the MC result from generating two independent exponentials and taking new expectations. Just wondering how you get the change of variables for $x$ and $y$.